# Using OR in SQL delete

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

There is a table 'collection' which has the following columns - id, cid , cname, cdescription, isviewed.

I use the following query for deletion based on a WHERE clause.

```
delete from collection
where cname not like '/mnt/sdcard%';
```

While I try to add one more condition to the above query using OR, the condition does not apply and the rows get deleted without applying the WHERE clause at all

```
delete from collection
where cname not like '/mnt/sdcard%' OR isviewed not like '1';
```

Is this not the correct syntax to use OR condition in delete? If yes, what need to be done in order that either of the condition in WHERE clause apply?

Comment: Without an example of your data, table structures, and outcome vs. expected outcome people can only guess at what might or might not be happening and why. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are the contents of the `isviewed` column numbers or strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from collection
where 
cname not like '/mnt/sdcard%' OR 
isviewed not like '1%';
```

This must have to do with the match part in your like sub-query. By specifying:

> '1%'

you are screening for all values of isviewed beginning with 1 assuming that is what you were after.

Consider

> '%1%'

if you were looking for presence of the character '1'
or

> '%1'
>   if you were looking for the string to end with '1'
>    or

Answer (score 0):

While @Spade solution works because `LIKE` will work regardless of column's data type, I don't think that `isviewed` column should be filtered by 'like'. To me it sounds like an `INT` column that stores either `1` or `0` value.

If that's the case then instead of using `like` just use:

```
delete from collection
where cname not like '/mnt/sdcard%' OR isviewed != 1;
```

This way it'll be more performant than using `LIKE`.

Comment: The filtering would work regardless of the data type in my answer, so it is a workable solution given we do not know what the actual data type is :-)